# How to update UILabel in applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: iphone, uilabel, uiapplicationdelegate

I need help with updating a label through in `applicationDidBecomeActive`. The way my project is structured, I have a RootViewController. When the user touches a button, a new view controller is opened through `presentModalView`. I want to update the label on this view controller each time the application becomes active. This is my code in my app delegate:

```
WordList1 *viewController1 = [[WordList1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"WordList1" bundle:nil];
[viewController1 changelabel:counter];
[viewController1 release];
```

And it calls this function in my WordList1 viewcontroller to update the label each time:

```
  - (void) changelabel:(int)counter {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter];  
    label.text = string;
}
```

When I run it through debugger, the value of "counter" and "string" are updating, but the label is not changing values. Please help

Comment: using break points can you check whether your label variable is initialized properly or not...

Comment: ya the label is perfectly initialized, because I can update it locally from WordList1, just not through appdelegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where have you created your `UILabel`?  If it is created through your xib file, make sure you have connected the File Owner's `IBOutlet` to the correct label.  If not connected, it does not know what label to update.

EDIT:
I believe that updating your label from the AppDelegate is bad code design.  The label should really be updated from a view controller.  My guess is that you are putting the code in the AppDelegate because that's where the code is that is called when the app enters the foreground.  To update the label from a view controller when the app enters the foreground, you can set up a notification in the view controller.  Code example:

```
- (id)init
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(changeLabel:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
    return self;
}
```

This registers the view controller as an observer to be notified each time the app will enter the foreground.  This way, you can contain this code in your view controller, and have it be updated accordingly.

Also, make sure you unregister the observer when the view controller is deallocated, by adding the following to your dealloc method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: The UILabel is created in IB and is connected through IBOutlet. The label is updating because I created a button that calls the "changelabel" function from WordList1 instead of the appdelegate and that updates the label correctly. However, the label is not getting updated from appdelegate

Comment: In your code, you create a new instance of the 'WordList1' view controller, called 'viewController'.  But, when you call the changeLabel method, you are calling it from viewController1.

Comment: oops sorry for the typo. both are supposed to be the same. I just forgot to type it when I was creating the question

Comment: Just check your code that you are creating a variable of `WordList1` only one time.

Comment: thanks!!! and where do I put that in my viewController? sorry for being a noob, but do I have to initialize it anywhere or call the (id)init at all? and do I put anything in the AppDidBecomeActive in the appdelegate?

Comment: The (id)init method would go in the implementation file for your view controller.  This would get called when you initialize an instance of that view controller class.  So, each time you initialize an instance, it registers to be notified when the app will enter the foreground.  Nothing is needed in the AppDidBecomeActive in the app delegate.  We were all noobs once :)

Answer (score 0):

In your appdelegate code, you never use ViewController1. It's not set as rootViewController, nor pushed nor nothing?  I don't understand how it can display anything?

Comment: The way the app is structured, the user will first go to WordList1 and then put the app to sleep, and when the app becomes active again, it is supposed to update the label on the screen

Comment: My point is that the code you're showing creates a new WordList1 and then destroys it.  It has nothing to do with what's on the screen.  You need to create a WordList1 when you start up and SAVE it, say as a instance variable in AppDelegate, not try and create a new one each time.  So, if this code is in applicationDidBecomeActive: , just (a) define viewController1 as a property, changing "viewController1" to "viewController1" everywhere (b) move the alloc/init line to application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (c) delete the release line  and you should be good.